# IE8 removing border around some parts of my fieldset. Confused.. Works in ie6 and ie7

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Anyone have any ideas why the left and right border around first name and last name disappear in IE8.  It works fine in firefox, ie6, ie7 and chrome.

http://amc.hsac.com.php5-10.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com/waiver.html

I am at a bit of a loss. Page validates.

*Update*

If you enter some bogus information, and get to the 2nd page, you will see the same problem in ie8.  It looks like it puts the appropriate borders around the fieldset on exactly half of the fieldset..

Comment: Can you post the css for that section?

Comment: Consider posting your solution as an answer, so that this question doesn't stay in the unanswered section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out!  Apparently ie8 does not like legends set with display:none. (which was the case).  I found an article that basically suggested putting spans inside the legend and putting display: none on it.  Problem solved!  (the other thing I coulda done was just removed the legends.. but I figured I would keep them there for accessibility.

http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2009/05/19/fieldset-and-legend-bug-in-ie8/